# apex:chart in JQuery Mobile not displaying correctly

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I am trying to display apex:chart inside jquery mobile. When I view the chart it looks like:
[image: The whole chart is in one place]

The whole chart is crammed in one place. 
When I refresh the page the chart displays correctly. My code is below:

```
<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos jqm-demos-index" id="Charts">

    <div data-role="header" class="jqm-header">
        <h1 class="jqm-logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.SalesIOLogo, '')}" alt="SalesIO" />
            </a>
        </h1>
        <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Navigation</a>
    </div>

    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <apex:chart height="400" width="300" animate="false" legend="true" data="{!data}" 
                    name="MyAreaChart" theme="Category1" resizable="false" rendered="true">

            <apex:legend position="left"/>

            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data1,data2,data3" 
                       title="Closed Won" grid="true">
                <apex:chartLabel />
            </apex:axis>

            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" 
                       title="Month of the Year">
                <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
            </apex:axis>

            <apex:areaSeries axis="left" xField="name" yField="data1,data2,data3" tips="true" />
        </apex:chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix the chart to display correctly.

Comment: Does it happen in more than 1 browser? Any errors in JS console? Any plugins like Adblock that are worth checking? Does the chart work OK in a page that doesn't reference jQuery Mobile? If it gets fixed after a refresh I wonder if there are any conflicings "onload" / "document.ready" events...

Comment: It happens in Chrome and Safari. No erros in JS console. No Adblock. Yes chart works fine if all apex syntax. I think the error is that I specify the width and width in apex:chart and JQuery mobile autoscale every for mobile device. As it cannot get the scale the heigh and width in the apex:chart is does not know how to render (set width and height) it...that is my theory.

Comment: Do you have the `<meta name="viewport"`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10905311 and also mentioned in http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Comment: Yes already have viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

Comment: I've asked the VF folks, but there's no easy fix, I'm afraid. The thing to do would be to look at jQuery Mobile and see if there is a way to 'hint' the height/width. I'll take a look if I can, but no promises.

Comment: Thanks metadaddy. I have used another js graph library instead.